# JPA CriteriaBuilder - Change default join type

Tags: java, jpa

I'd like to change the default join type from the criteriaBuilder from INNER to LEFT. Is this possible in some way? Atm I'm doing things like:

```
    Join<Request, Ship> requestShipJoin = requestRoot.join("ship", JoinType.LEFT);
    Join<Ship, Visit> shipVisitJoin = requestShipJoin.join("visit", JoinType.LEFT);
```

I've got a lot of nullable foreign keys, but if the FK is null the result still has to return (used with ordening). I'm hoping that this is possible since all the joins that I have to do are of type LEFT.

Comment: If there's no setting you could write a little utility that wraps the original join.

Comment: @RobertMoskal That are thing that I'd like to avoid. I can't imagine this isn't in the framework somewhere actually.. JPA would really disappoint me ^^

Comment: since JPA does NOT come with such a thing, then you will have to do something implementation dependent either way

Comment: @NeilStockton Well the question here is if JPA REALLY doesn't have something like that. But it indeed seems it doesn't..

Comment: That's java for you! A big aircraft carrier.